# Nested SQL Query, what is actually occurring at each nesting?

Tags: mysql, database

I was wondering how this query works:

```
SELECT empname FROM Employee WHERE not exists (
    SELECT projid FROM Project WHERE not exists (
        SELECT empid, projid FROM Assigned WHERE empid = Employee.empid and projid = Project.projid
    )
)
```

It is supposed to return names of all employees who are assigned to every project and it does work however I am getting confused as to how/why it works correctly.

Schema is:

> Employee(empID INT,empName VARCHAR(100),job VARCHAR(100),deptID INT,salary INT);
>   Assigned(empID INT,projID INT,role VARCHAR(100));
>   Project(projID INT,title VARCHAR(100),budget INT,funds INT);

I am new to SQL so a detailed/simple explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I need to try to understand what's going on, I look for the inner-most query and work my way outwards.  In your case, let's start with:

```
SELECT empid, projid 
FROM Assigned 
WHERE empid = Employee.empid and projid = Project.projid
```

This is matching all records in the Assigned table where the empid and projid are in the previous tables (hence the Employee.empid and Project.projid).

Assume there are 5 projects in the Projects table and Employee1 is assigned to each.  That would return 5 records.  Also assume Employee2 is assigned to 1 of those projects, thus returning 1 record.

Next look at:

```
SELECT projid FROM Project WHERE not exists (
        ...
    )
```

Now this says for those found records in the previous query (Employee1 with 5 projects and Employee2 with 1 project), select any projid from the Project table where there aren't any matches (not exists) from the previous query.  In other words, Employee1 would return no projects from this query but Employee2 would return 4 projects.

Finally, look at

```
 SELECT empname FROM Employee WHERE not exists (
        ...
    )
```

Just as with the 2nd query, for any records found in the previous query (no records to match those employees with all projects such as Employee1 and some records if the employee isn't assigned to every project such as Employee2), select any employee from the Employee table where there aren't any matches (again, not exists).  In other words, Employee1 would return since no projects were returned from the previous query, and Employee2 would not return, since 1 or more projects were returned from the previous query.

Hope this helps.  Here's some additional information about EXISTS:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

And from that article:

> What kind of store is present in all cities?

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_type FROM stores s1   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM cities WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM cities_stores
       WHERE cities_stores.city = cities.city AND cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type));
```

> The last example is a double-nested NOT EXISTS query. That is, it has
>   a NOT EXISTS clause within a NOT EXISTS clause. Formally, it answers
>   the question “does a city exist with a store that is not in Stores”?
>   But it is easier to say that a nested NOT EXISTS answers the question
>   “is x TRUE for all y?”

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A `NOT EXISTS (subquery)` predicate will return TRUE when the resultset from the subquery has no rows. It will return FALSE when a matching row is found.

Essentially, the query is asking

for each row in Employee... check each row from the Project table, to see if there is a row in the Assigned table for a row that has an empid that matches the empid on the Employee row and a projid that matches a row in the Project table.

The row from Employee will be returned only if no matching row is found.

Note that the expressions in the SELECT list of the subquery are not important; all that is being checked is whether that subquery returns one (or more) rows or not. Normally, we use a literal 1 in the SELECT list; that remind us that what we are checking is whether a row is found or not.)

I would typically write that query in a style that looks like this:

```
SELECT e.empname 
  FROM Employee e 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM Project p
          WHERE NOT EXISTS
                ( SELECT 1 
                    FROM Assigned a 
                   WHERE a.empid = e.empid
                     AND a.projid = p.projid
                )
       )
```

And I read the "`SELECT 1`" as "select one row")

The resultset from that query is essentially equivalent to the resultset from this (usually much less efficient) query:

```
SELECT e.empname
  FROM Employee e
 WHERE e.empid NOT IN
       ( SELECT a.empid
           FROM Assigned a
           JOIN Project p
             ON a.projid = p.projid
         WHERE a.empid IS NOT NULL
          GROUP
             BY a.empid
       )
```

The `NOT IN` query can be a little easier to understand, because you can run that subquery and see that it returns something. (What can be kind of confusing about the NOT EXISTS subquery is that it doesn't matter what expressions are returned in the SELECT list; what matters is whether a row is returned or not.)  There are some "gotchas" with the NOT IN subquery besides really bad performance; you need to be careful to ensure that the subquery does not return a NULL value, because then the NOT IN (NULL,...) will never return true.

An equivalent resultset can be returned using an anti-join pattern as well:

```
SELECT e.empname
  FROM Employee e
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT a.empid
           FROM Assigned a
           JOIN Project p
             ON a.projid = p.projid
         WHERE a.empid IS NOT NULL
          GROUP
             BY a.empid
       ) o
    ON o.empid = e.empid
WHERE o.empid IS NULL
```

In that query, we are looking for "matches" on empid. The LEFT keyword tells MySQL to also return any rows from Employee (the table one the left side of the JOIN) which do not have a match. For those rows, a NULL value is returned in place of the values of the columns that would have been returned if there had been a matching row.  The "trick" is then to throw out all the rows that matched. We do that by checking for a NULL in a column that would not be NULL if there had been a match.

If I were going to write this query using a `NOT EXISTS` predicate, I would probably actually favor writing it like this:

```
SELECT e.empname
  FROM Employee e
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM Assigned a
           JOIN Project p
             ON a.projid = p.projid
          WHERE a.empid = e.empid
       )
```